# Select_tag submitted needs to redirect to show page with :id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, html-select

Hi
I have asked a question similar to this before but never got it resolved. So I am trying again.

This seems like it should be so simple. I am not using Rails 3 yet BTW.

All I want to do is have a drop down menu and when a person chooses that location and presses "go" they go to that page.

```
    <% form_tag installation_path([:id]), :url => { :action => "show" }, :method => :get do %>
<%= select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(Installation.find(:all), :id, :name) %>
<%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
<% end %>
```

This becomes the issue: http://localhost:3000/installations/id?id=1&commit=Create. It can't find the :id. I just don't know how to route this correctly. It seems like this shouldn't be that difficult.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What's in your routes? installations/id? is definitely not right. If you do normal Rails routing then your show action should be installations/:id

Comment: I just have restful routes map.resources :installations, it seems like I need to do something in the routes I just can't figure out what that is. I believe it automatically uses the route installations/id? because I need to use the :get method. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be a problem with your form_tag. It seems you're defining the path twice.

Both

```
installation_path([:id])
```

and

```
:url => { :action => "show" }
```

are used to generate the path but I don't think you should be using both. Just go with

```
installation_path([:id])
```

or

```
:url => { :controller => "installations", :action => "show", :id => id }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and use a new "show" route that is not based on the installation id (and doesn't collide with Rails resource routes), and continue to send the installation id into the controller's show action as part of the params object.

In routes.rb,

```
get 'show_installation', to: 'installations#show'
```

In your view,

```
<% form_tag show_installation_path, :method => :get %>
...
```